# Devise Lockable not working in rspec controller tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

We have a custom SessionsController that inherits from the standard Devise::SessionsController and have lockable enabled for the User model. This works when testing manually, but in our controller tests `failed_attempts` is not incrementing beyond 1. If I reduce `maximum_attempts` attempts to 1 it will successfully lock the account in testing, but it still will not increment `failed_attempts` beyond 1.

Below is my test example. Any ideas as to why `failed_attempts` is not incrementing beyond one 1 controller tests?

```
it{
  bad_user = create(:user, password: 'passworD1')
  3.times do
    post :create, user: { email: bad_user.email, password: 'asdf' }
  end

  post :create, user: { email: bad_user.email, password: 'asdf' }
  bad_user.reload
  expect(bad_user.failed_attempts).to eq(4)
  expect(bad_user.locked_at).not_to be_blank
}
```

Comment: Are you changing the behaviour of `Lockable` somehow? Because if you aren't, I don't think you need to test something that is already [well tested](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/7ca70a47ce7be5f6691d7408eb1eb332974477d6/test/models/lockable_test.rb) in Devise itself.

Comment: I'm not, but I want to test that the behavior works as expected and is configured correctly. Also, devise may be widely used but it is still software with dependencies, so it should be tested.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Yeah, did you ever solved this?

Answer (score 3):

I tried this method warden.clear_strategies_cache! after post and I was able to lock the account.

For your example it would look like this:

```
it{
  bad_user = create(:user, password: 'passworD1')
  3.times do
    post :create, user: { email: bad_user.email, password: 'asdf' }
    warden.clear_strategies_cache!
  end

  post :create, user: { email: bad_user.email, password: 'asdf' }
  bad_user.reload
  expect(bad_user.failed_attempts).to eq(4)
  expect(bad_user.locked_at).not_to be_blank
}
```

Regards,
Ruslan

Comment: This worked for me! Small thing to add:
`warden.clear_strategies_cache!` will clear the cache of your default scope (i.e., user). But if the one you want to clear is not the default one (i.e., admin) you should precise which one you want to clear (i.e., `warden.clear_strategies_cache! (scope: :admin)`

Answer (score 2):

Per [Devise lockable module](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/lockable.rb)
There is a method lock_access! which locks access. That's one way to test another - brute force. Enter right email and wrong password at new_user_session_path as many time as needed per devise initializer then test new_user_unlock_path.